# Where should I ask a question about a possible postscript exploit?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, subdomains, exploit

There is a file which is way too big to be a valid postscript file.

It could be just a honest mistake by the creator, or it could be an exploit.

If it is an exploit, does it belong to [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or rather to [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

How should the (1.5 MB) code be posted? (VirusTotal did not find it to be malware)

---

As of @Patrick's question, this is about **identifying it as an exploit and getting a description how it works**.

As of [his suggestion to post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261766/289870), there is now [a question on meta.security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/how-to-ask-about-suspicious-1-8mb-eps-file).

Comment: One thing you can do is search on Stack Exchange main site, which will show you what sites have the keywords. Such as searching for [postscript exploit](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=postscript%20exploit)

Comment: Don't post malware or suspected malware. We aren't VirusTotal.

Comment: @DeerHunter: Thank you, also for the reference to VirusTotal (which did not find anything)

Comment: @James: There are more posts in security, some in tex, codegolf, unix, serverfault, askubuntu, all on the first page. None in reverseengineering (which is beta, so that might be expected). What did you mean?

Comment: The first part of your question can be on-topic, the last one 'help me understand ...' is too broad to fit in any SE site.

Comment: The search option I gave shows you Stack Exchange sites with the keywords you would type into a question you would ask. So it shows sites which *possibly* allow your question. It's not perfect, but given your question is quite a niche topic I thought it might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [quite some questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bexploit%5D%20is%20this) on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) which ask to tell if a specific anomaly is an exploit. So are highly up-voted, some are closed. It seems to be a subject that is allowed to ask, but you need to make sure it is understandable and clear.

If you ask there, maybe first go to their [meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/) and ask how to formulate this question best, and if they thing it is allowed at all. Also, a 1.5 MB file seems a lot of code to post, and I am not sure how this will be received. If you can, try to narrow it down and make clear what you have done already to find the answer yourself.